# C3JS Acces value shown on X axis

Tags: data-visualization, c3.js

I have simple bar chart like this:

Here is my C3JS

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
json:[{"A": 67, "B": 10, "site": "Google", "C": 12}, {"A": 10, "B": 20, "site": "Amazon", "C": 12}, {"A": 25, "B": 10, "site": "Stackoverflow", "C": 8}, {"A": 20, "B": 22, "site": "Yahoo", "C": 12}, {"A": 76, "B": 30, "site": "eBay", "C": 9}],
        mimeType: 'json',
     keys: {
         x: 'site',
         value: ['A','B','C']
     },
     type: 'bar',
     selection: {
   enabled: true
     },
     onselected: function(d,element)
     {   
      alert('selected x: '+chart.selected()[0].x+' value: '+chart.selected()[0].value+' name: '+chart.selected()[0].name);
     },
     groups: [
         ['A','B','C']
     ]
 },
 axis: {
     x: {
 type: 'category'
        }
      }
});
```

After some chart elemnt is selected (clicked), alert shows X and Value and Name attributes of first selected element. For example "selected x: 0 value: 67 name: A" after I click on left-top chart element. How can I get value shown on X axis? In this case it is "Google".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property categories is populated when the x-axis is declared to be of type category as it is in this case. So to get the data from the x-axis you needs to call the .categories() function.

```
onselected: function(d,element){alert(chart.categories()[d.index]);}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4bos2qzx/1/